# FileSystemWatcher as a Windows Service using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, windows-services, filesystemwatcher

So, I have created a windows service, where I use a `FileSystemWatcher` to watch different directories. Every time changed files are detected I copy them in a different directory, so I can work with them later.

This **works perfectly** when I run the program as a *Console Application*.

When I run it as a *service*, I can start and stop the service **properly**, but **it won't detect any kind of event.** I have tried to debug my service and I found out that the error is coming from the fact that I don't stop the `FileSystemWatcher`.

For my console App, I have this code for the `Watch()` method:

```
    public void Watch()
    {
        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher($"C:\\Users\\wost\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime", _ext))
        {
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            watcher.Created += OnChanged;
            watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
            watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // Wait for the user to quit the program.
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
        }
    }
```

So, I stop the program if the user presses 'q'.

For my Windows Service, I have this code for the `Watch()` method:

```
 public void Watch()
    {
        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher($"C:\\Users\\lashi\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 3", _ext))
        {
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                 | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                 | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                 | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
            watcher.Created += OnChanged;
            watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
            watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        }
    }
```

So, here I don't stop the `FileSystemWatcher` at all, because as I don't have a direct interaction with the user, I don't know how to stop it. Can you please help me to find a solution to this?

These are the `OnStart()` and `OnStop()` methods:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    Watcher w;
    
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        w = new Watcher($"C:\\EMMC_CACHE\\expt1-log", $"C:\\EMMC_CACHE\\expt1-file", "lashi");
        w.Watch();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\wost\Desktop\FILES");
        int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
        // TEST
        if (count == 0)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\wost\Desktop\Notes.txt");
            writer.WriteLine("Service is stopped at: " + DateTime.Now);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that in the Windows Service at the end of the `Watch` method you `Dispose` the `FileSystemWatcher` instance because the `using` blocks exits.

The first thing to do my opion is to remove the using block here and the 2nd to declare the watcher as a *field* of the class. 
And 3rd would be to implement the `Dispose` pattern.
But first things first....

Comment: In the Console version you don't exit, there you have a "wait loop" like `while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;`

Comment: @lidqy Thank you for your answer! I tried to get rid of the 'using' statement, but I still have the same result.

Comment: @MickyD Thank you for your answer! Yes, I have changed the account, but I got the same result.

Comment: @MickyD To the enterpriseAdmin as I am using an enterprise PC.

Comment: I could solve a very similar problem with 'topshelf' (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y64L-3HKuP0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to make the watcher a field and not to dispose it prematurely. I didn't test this code but you see the relevant changes in 'Watch', i think....

```
internal class Watcher : IDisposable {

    private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;
    private string _directoryPath;  
    private string _ext;
    
    internal Watcher (string directoryPath, string ext) {
            _directoryPath = directoryPath;
            _ext = ext;
    }
    ~Watcher () {
        Dispose();
    }
    public void Watch()
    {
        Dispose();
        
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_directoryPath, _ext);
        
        _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                             | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName
                             | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        // Add event handlers.
        _watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        _watcher.Created += OnChanged;
        _watcher.Deleted += OnChanged;
        _watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

        // Begin watching.
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
    
     public void Dispose() {
        try {
           _watcher?.Dispose();
        } catch {
           ;
        }
        _watcher = null;
     }
     //FSW event handlers...

}
```

Comment: Doh! You beat me! +1   :)

Comment: @lidqy Thank you for taking your time to propose this solution! I just tried it, but I am still having the same result! I can't understand where the error is coming from.

Comment: AT WillWost Hhm. It might have something to with the user context the service runs in and its fs access privilges, as @MickyD pointed out. Or, but that's just a guess, that another instance of the watcher is still running (I just assume that this could cause trouble, fully imaginary).
Or of course that  real code you execituing /whic is surely different from the tokens you've posted and more complex) still has another issue, not visible to the forum.

Comment: @lidqy Apparently, after retrying it, your solution worked correctly. Thank you for that!